# Setting Timezone for date function in python

Tags: python

I have this below function that pulls data from an API function based on start date and end date. I have to specify 2 time zones based on the data I am sending to the API. The timezones that I am working are IST and EDT (USA).

Please let me know how I can set the timezone for startDate and endDate variables.

```
startDate = dt.datetime.today() - dt.timedelta(days=2 * 365)
endDate = dt.datetime.today()
data.getDataset(stock = stock, startDate = startDate, endDate = endDate, con = con)
```

Comment: [This link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/working-with-datetime-objects-and-timezones-in-python/) will be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from pytz import timezone
import pytz

for tz in pytz.all_timezones:
    print(tz)
            
# and then select what you need:
startDate = datetime.now(pytz.timezone("Asia/Calcutta")) - timedelta(days=2 * 365)
```

Comment: May I know how to assign this tz value to start Date and endDate ?

Comment: @SatheeshKumar. I will update the answer with below. Please see the update answer.
startDate = datetime.now(pytz.timezone("Asia/Calcutta")) - timedelta(days=2 * 365)

Answer (score 1):

> how I can set the timezone for startDate and endDate variables

Without using other libs and just datetime, I think you can accomplish it like this (note: I had changed the imports)

```py
from datetime import timezone, datetime, timedelta

TZ_IST = timezone(timedelta(hours=5.5))
startDate = datetime.now(tz=TZ_IST) - timedelta(days=2 * 365)
endDate = datetime.now(tz=TZ_IST)
print(startDate)
print(endDate)

TZ_EDT = timezone(timedelta(hours=-4))
startDate = datetime.now(tz=TZ_EDT) - timedelta(days=2 * 365)
endDate = endDate.now(tz=TZ_EDT)
print(startDate)
print(endDate)

# data.getDataset(stock = stock, startDate = startDate, endDate = endDate, con = con)
```

The output

```
2021-10-04 23:32:09.447763+05:30
2023-10-04 23:32:09.447763+05:30

2021-10-04 14:02:09.447763-04:00
2023-10-04 14:02:09.447763-04:00
```

I have checked the world clocks and it seemed correct.

[image]
[image]

`today()` [does not accept tz as an arg](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.today) since it only has the date portion and not time.

Since you're asking about timezone, I imagine you're working on something that is time-sensitive, so `now()` would be more suitable as [it also accepts `tz` as argument](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now)

Answer (score 0):

I am basically copy-pasting this [geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/working-with-datetime-objects-and-timezones-in-python/) tutorial. Use `pytz` to "lozalize" your datetime object, i.e. make it aware of the timezone.

```py
import datetime
import pytz

# defining the objects
startDate = datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=2 * 365)
endDate = datetime.datetime.today()

# Defining the timezone
ist_tz = pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata')
edt_tz = pytz.timezone('EST5EDT')  # Careful with EDT

# localising the objects to the timezone
startDate_ist = ist_tz.localize(startDate)
startDate_edt = edt_tz.localize(startDate)
endDate_ist = ist_tz.localize(endDate)
endDate_edt = edt_tz.localize(endDate)

# printing the dates
print(f"startDate_ist: {startDate_ist}")
print(f"startDate_edt: {startDate_edt}")
print(f"endDate_ist: {endDate_ist}")
print(f"endDate_edt: {endDate_edt}")

# printing the differences
print(endDate_edt-endDate_ist)
print(endDate_edt-startDate_ist)
```

Comment: startDate_ist: 2021-10-05 10:47:56.158303+05:30
startDate_edt: 2021-10-05 10:47:56.158303-04:00
endDate_ist: 2023-10-05 10:47:56.158303+05:30
endDate_edt: 2023-10-05 10:47:56.158303-04:00
9:30:00
730 days, 9:30:00 I am getting the above output.. the time is same for both IST and EDT

Comment: Look more carefully, the time is not the same. The time you get is UTC, then you have +05:30 for IST and -04:00 for EDT.